# While loop and try and catch

Tags: c#

The code tells me when the input is not a number, but it also writes the else if code at the same time.
I belive it has something to do with me assigning the number 0 to doubleNr at the top double varible, but if I don't, I get ***Use of unassigned local variable 'doubleNr'*** in the while condition.
Also, where am I supose to write the ***doubleNr = myMethod(intNr);*** line?
In the try block or between the catch and the if block?

```
int intNr;
double doubleNr = 0;

while (doubleNr < 20 || doubleNr > 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
    string strNr = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        intNr = Convert.ToInt32(strNr);
        doubleNr = myMethod(intNr);  // Should this line go here?
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number must be INT");
    }
    // or should it go here?

    if (doubleNr < 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a higher number.");
    }
    else if (doubleNr > 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a lower number.");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("That is a good number.");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use try/catch to control the flow of your program

Comment: Move your if/else if statements inside your try block and you should be good

Comment: `doubleNr < 20 || doubleNr < 30` this makes no sense, it's equivalent to saying `doubleNr < 30` so why use two conditions here?

Comment: I guess that's a typo @Toby. Look at OP `if`structure: `if (doubleNr < 20) ...else if (doubleNr > 30)`

Comment: If you can't be sure about the input is integer, don't use `Convert()`, use `int.TryPase()`. That will give boolean result, if resul is false, so "Number must be INT".

Comment: @Pikoh - But the assignment says I'm supose to use try/catch for this.

Comment: @Pikoh Right yes that makes sense. It's just really confusing to read this code. The `try-catch` seems to be really useless when using a `while` loop here.

Comment: @Toby - Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Yeah @Tenakey i don't blame you. Some teachers just don't know how to put try/catch excercises that don't lead to bad habits...

Comment: @FCin Thank you, but I'm told by the teacher to only put to convertion inside the try block.

Comment: @Pikoh Dosn't feel very good that I'm learning the wrong way :( Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: just use `continue;` every time you want to skip the current loop execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably isn't worth the answer but I just want to point out some things in your code. Since you are expected to use `try-catch` you can simple implement a `retry-catch`. To do this, you should just use `while(true)` with your try-catch logic controlling the flow of your program as said by @Pikoh.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intNr;
    double doubleNr = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
            string strNr = Console.ReadLine();
            doubleNr = Int32.Parse(strNr);
            if(doubleNr < 20)
            {
                throw new Exception("Try a higher number.");
            }
            else if(doubleNr > 30)
            {
                throw new Exception("Try a lower number.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is a good number.");
                break;
            }
        }
        catch(FormatException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid number.");
            continue;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see that it isn't the `while` loop conditioning your program, the `try-catch` logic will control it. Of course there are other ways of doing this too but this is just a restructuring of your code.

Just so you're aware, there are better ways to also do this. You can use `Int32.TryParse()` which would be best in this case. No need to use any `try-catch` blocks.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int intNr;
    double doubleNr = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
        string strNr = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        if(Int32.TryParse(strNr, out value))
        {
            doubleNr = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid number: ");
            continue;
        }
        if(doubleNr < 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try a higher number.");
            continue;
        }
        else if(doubleNr > 30)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try a lower number.");
            continue;
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is a good number."); 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip current loop step in case of exception or any other condition, use[continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) statement.

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
>   enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in which it appears.

This your code example with `continue` statements.

```
int intNr;
double doubleNr = 0;

while (doubleNr < 20 || doubleNr > 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
    string strNr = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        intNr = Convert.ToInt32(strNr);
        // if you want to catch any exceptions in this method then leave it there 
        // otherwise you can move it outside try/catch block            
        doubleNr = myMethod(intNr);  

    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number must be INT");
        continue; // return to the beginning of your loop
    }

    if (doubleNr < 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a higher number.");
        continue; // return to the beginning of your loop
    }
    // do not need else since code wont reach this line if doubleNr is < 20
    if (doubleNr > 30) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a lower number.");                        
        continue; // return to the beginning of your loop
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("That is a good number.");
```